# How come it doesn't display my values using ajax from php

Tags: php, jquery

I am expecting a list of values from my php code

PHP CODE:

```
    $warriors = array();

foreach($result as $names){
    $warriors[] = $names;
}
echo json_encode($warriors);
```

JS FUNCTION:

```
function getWarriors() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "display_warriors.php",
            datatype:"json",
            success: function(data) {
                var toAppend = '';
                if(typeof data === "object"){
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        var warrior = data[i];
                        toAppend += '<tr>';
                        toAppend += '<td>'+data[i]['warrior_id']+'</td>';
                        toAppend += '<td>'+data[i]['warrior_name']+'</td>';
                        toAppend += '<td>'+data[i]['warrior_type']+'</td>';
                        toAppend += '</tr>';
                    }
                    $("#listWarriors table").append(toAppend);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

HTML CODE TO CALL FUNCTION

```
<li><a href="#listWarriors" onclick="return getWarriors()">Warrior List</a></li>
```

When I click the a tag it does not display what I am expecting, what could be wrong

Comment: have you checked the alert(data)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to set the headers to "application/json"

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

I ran into something similar and had to specify that I was sending JSON specifically.  It may help.

Comment: @BrainedWashed In the PHP file. At the top.

Comment: yes it works but everytime I click my a tag it dupticates the display example output-------1